# How to reverse effect of a JS action using an IF ELSE statement using Global variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

Creating a very basic **IF ELSE** statement in JavaScript to create a clickable overlay on a DIV. The open action works however close does not.

Using the onClick function to select the div, with the idea a var will tell it whether to run the function or not.

```
<div onclick="myFunction()" class="outer">

<div class="inner" id="overlay">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>What is Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry Lorem Ipsum has been the industry'sstrong text standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book it has?</p>
</div>
```

```
.outer {
position: relative;
width: 25rem; 
height: 15rem;
border-radius: 1em;
background-image: url("https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16360374/37567282-e1932872-2a81-11e8-807b-efc5a997f2f1.jpg");
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888888;
  overflow: hidden;
}
  
.inner {
position: absolute; 
bottom: 0; 
width: 100%;
height: 5rem; 
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.inner > * {
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```
function myFunction() {

  var overlay = false;
  
 if(overlay == false) { document.getElementById("overlay").style.height = "100%";
overlay = true;
}
else
{document.getElementById("overlay").style.height = "20%";
overlay = false;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `myFunction` you always set the *local* variable overlay to false. This means that when you check the value of overlay it is always false.

You need to move the variable to a higher scope in order for it to persist its value between different calls to `myFunction`.

Try to create the variable outside `myFunction` like this instead.

```js
var overlay = false;
function myFunction() {
  if(overlay == false) {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.height = "100%";
    overlay = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.height = "20%";
    overlay = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you run myFunction() the overlay variable is set to false. This making the height always set to 100%.

Placing the overlay variable outside the myFunction() fixed the problem! Now since the overlay variable is global, it switches states when clicked on [hidded <==> shown].

```js
let overlay = false;
       
function myFunction() {
if(overlay == false) {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.height = "100%";
  overlay = true;
} else {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.height = "20%";
  overlay = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **overlay** variable will always be false. Move **overlay** out of the function.

```
  var overlay = false;  
  function myFunction() {
     if(overlay == false) { 
      document.getElementById("overlay").style.height = "100%";
      overlay = true;
     } else {
      document.getElementById("overlay").style.height = "20%";
      overlay = false;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 versions of solutions.

1. Uses the global variable to keep track of overlay status
2. Uses the element data-attribute parameter instead of a global variable
3. Uses the 'id' and data-attribute without the global variable

> `

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title> Image Overlays Page </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
    
    <!-- From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538838/how-to-reverse-effect-of-a-js-action-using-an-if-else-statement-using-global-var -->
    <style>
     .outer {
       position: relative;
       width: 25rem; 
       height: 15rem;
       border-radius: 1em;
       background-image: url("https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16360374/37567282-e1932872-2a81-11e8-807b-efc5a997f2f1.jpg");
       background-position: center;
       background-size: cover;
       box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888888;
       overflow: hidden;
     }
     .inner {
       position: absolute; 
       bottom: 0; 
       width: 100%;
       height: 20%; 
       background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
       border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
       border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
       transition: 0.5s;
     }
     .inner > * {
       color: white;
       padding: 1rem;
     }
     h1 { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
     div { display: inline-block; } /* optional setting */
    </style>
    </head><body>
    
    <div onclick="myFunction()" class="outer">
     <div class="inner" id="overlay">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>What is Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry 
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's strong text standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
    when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book it has?</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div onclick="myFunction2()" class="outer" data-overlay='false'>
     <div class="inner" id="overlay2">
      <h1>Title 2</h1>
      <p>What is Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</p>
      <p>This version uses an internal status data-attribute.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div onclick="myFunction3('overlay3')" class="outer" data-overlay='false'>
     <div class="inner" id="overlay3">
      <h1>Title 3</h1>
      <p><br />This version uses element 'ID' and data-attribute.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
      console.clear();
    
    /* Version #1 - uses global variable */
      var overlay = false;  
      function myFunction() {
        overlay = !overlay;
        let ht = (overlay) ? '100%' : '20%'; 
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.height = ht;
      }
    /* */
    
    /* Version #2 - uses element attribute */
      function myFunction2() {
                let overlay = document.getElementById('overlay2');
        let status = overlay.getAttribute('data-overlay');
        if (status === 'false') { 
          overlay.style.height = '20%';  overlay.setAttribute('data-overlay','true');
        } else {
          overlay.style.height = '100%';   overlay.setAttribute('data-overlay','false');
        }
      }
    /* */
    
    /* Version #3 - uses ID and element attribute */
      function myFunction3(IDS) {
        let overlay = document.getElementById(IDS);
        let status = overlay.getAttribute('data-overlay');
        if (status === 'false') { 
          overlay.style.height = '20%';  overlay.setAttribute('data-overlay','true');
        } else {
          overlay.style.height = '100%';   overlay.setAttribute('data-overlay','false');
        }
      }
    /* */
    </script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

`